# Are there ways to copy methods from one TableAdapter to another?

Tags: c#, sql, methods, dataset, tableadapter

I've **created a DataSet** related with SQL server database. This DataSet has a set of tables with TableAdapters where I've written methods to access database data. Later **I've moved my database to another server**, changed a **connection string** and tried to update the DataSet. But the **Wizard just adds copies** of the tables with empty TableAdapters to the DataSet.

So now **I want to copy the methods** of original TableAdapters to the new ones and to delete original tables after. Can I do it? Or maybe someone show me another solution.

Comment: Close project and edit the xml configure file.  You should be able to copy sections of existing adapter into the new adapter.

Comment: I've tried this way but it has not worked. I could see the methods in project tree but they haven't shown in the DataSet. Probably I've done something wrong, but anyways this way doesn't look simple and convenient. Maybe there is a standard way to tune a DataSet when database has moved?

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the connection string or query.  The editing of the xml was correct if you saw it in the project tree.  So either the instance of the SQL Server is different in the new machine or there is no data in the database.  I would start by using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL Server and check instance name in login window.  Then try your query in new database and see if you get results.

Comment: Database was restored from backup and it's actually the same database as the original one. Just one difference that it was working on SQL Server 2014 and now it's working on SQL Server 2016. Guess that's a reason why I have this issue.

Comment: Yes.  That is why I said to check the instance of the form in the login window.

Comment: Thanks for help, I'll try to check it.

Comment: When you install the server the instance name can be changed so you do not need to have the version in the name.  Makes it easier if you have different server with difference version.  I have some of my window form project with a pulldown box to select server and depending on server the code includes the connection string with correct version of server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With many tries I've got the **solution**! It's pretty easy:

1. Open your **DataSet**.
2. Right-click on first table.
3. Click ***"Configure..."***.
4. Click ***"Done"***.
5. Repeat steps 3-4 with all of your tables.

If you got no errors your table is updated now!